# How can I extend an abstract class with an optional member in Scala?

Tags: scala, oop, abstract-class, case-class

I have an abstract base class, Foo, whose constructor I'd like to have an optional parameter. If none is provided, I'll just give it a `None` value.

A source Foo will not have parents, so I'd just like to construct them without a list of parents (leave default value for parent list)

A derived Foo might have provided parents, so I'd like to mimic the signature of the Foo base class.

Below is my attempt:

```
abstract class Foo(val id: String, var parentIds: Option[List[String]]=None) { }

case class SourceFoo(override val id: String)
  extends Foo(id, parentIds=None) { }

case class DerivedFoo(override val id: String, 
                      override var parentIds: Option[List[String]])
  extends Foo(id, parentIds) { }
```

I'm getting a compiler error that a mutable variable cannot be overridden (referencing the `parentIds` in the `DerivedFoo` constructor.

This list is subject to change, so I don't want to make it a `val` (which removes my compiler issues).

This is a very basic OO issue, so it must be simpler than I seem to be making it. How can I achieve my desired behavior idiomatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this after reading the [documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html):

> The constructor parameters of case classes are treated as public values and can be accessed directly.

Since my base class is abstract, I can simply extend it with default, `val` construction.

I simply need to specify that `parentIds` is a var in the DerivedFoo constructor.

```
abstract class Foo(id: String, parentIds: Option[List[String]]=None) { }

case class SourceFoo(id: String) extends Foo(id) { }

case class DerivedFoo(id: String, var parentIds: Option[List[String]]=None) 
    extends Foo(id, parentIds) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another probably better way to go about it. Explictly acknowledge the difference between class parameters and class members. You also can make them private members if you like following this block of code.

```
abstract class Foo(identifier: String, parentIdentifiers: Option[List[String]]) { 
  val id = identifier
  var parentIds = parentIdentifiers
}

case class SourceFoo(override val id: String) extends Foo(id, parentIdentifiers = None) { }

case class DerivedFoo(identifier: String, parentIdentifiers: Option[List[String]]) extends Foo(identifier, parentIdentifiers) { }
```

After that, you can create DerivedFoo and refer to the members as you are probably expecting, and you won't have two members with different names.

REPL output:

```
scala> DerivedFoo("1", Some(List("200","201","202")))
res0: DerivedFoo = DerivedFoo(1,Some(List(200, 201, 202)))

scala> res0.parentIds
res1: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(200, 201, 202))

scala> res0.parentIds = Some(List("800", "801", "802"))
res0.parentIds: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(800, 801, 802))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve your goal by changing the name of the parameter in the abstract class as follows.

```
abstract class Foo(val id: String, var parentIdentifiers: Option[List[String]]) { 
  parentIdentifiers = None
}

case class SourceFoo(override val id: String)
  extends Foo(id, parentIdentifiers = None) { }

case class DerivedFoo(override val id: String, 
                      var parentIds: Option[List[String]])
  extends Foo(id, parentIds) { }
```

Comment: Note that then `DerivedFoo` would have _both_ members, so make sure you access the right one. Maybe you'd want to give them more descriptive names to signify this - `parentIds` for the abstract class constructor and something like `preliminaryParentIds` for `DerivedFoo`'s constructor

Comment: This is the only solution? :(

Comment: No hang on I'll give you another in a few

Comment: @TzachZohar Anyway doesn't that two members thing get at the root of the issue? When he tries to override the var, if the compiler let him do that then there would still be two variables. The one in the subtype would be the same name and would "shadow" the super type variable. But anyway, the other answer I just posted gets back to what is probably The Right Way(TM)

Answer (score 0):

For the mutation, you can `import scala.collection.mutable` and use `mutable.ListBuffer` instead of `List`.
I assume of course, that you won't change the `parentIds` of a `DerivedFoo` instance from `Some` to `None`.
This will allow you use `val`s but still have mutable state.

***But I wouldn't say mutable state is idiomatic Scala.***

You usually use immutable `val` and `List`, and just copy the object whenever you want to change the list.

```
  val fooA = SourceFoo("a")
  val fooB = DerivedFoo("b", "a" :: Nil)
  val fooB2 = fooB.copy(parentIds = fooB.parentIds :+ "x")
```

So to be more idiomatic, the simplest you can do is

```
sealed abstract class Foo(val id: String, val parentIdsOpt: Option[List[String]])

case class SourceFoo(override val id: String)
  extends Foo(id, None)

case class DerivedFoo(override val id: String, val parentIds: List[String])
  extends Foo(id, Some(parentIds))
```

Which is pretty close to what you had.

Note that `DerivedFoo.parentIds` isn't `Option` anymore, because `DerivedFoo` always has parents, so you don't have to deal with `Option`. (You still have to deal with empty list, though)

Also note the `sealed` keyword on the trait, which is not required, but recommended if you want to match on an instance of the abstract class or trait. (You can use `sealed` only if you own all the sub-classes, which seems to be the case in your example)